# Figuring out the sign for Vandermonde determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

My assignment requires me to show for the following Vandermonde matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\x&y&z\\x^2&y^2&z^2\end{bmatrix}

the determinant is $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$.

But when I calculate, I got $(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)$. How do I change the sign so that I get $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)=[-(x-y)](z-x)[-(y-z)]=(-1)(-1)(x-y)(z-x)(y-z)=(x-y)(z-x)(y-z)$$
Because: $-(a-b)=-a-(-b)=-a+b=(b-a)$

Note: The multiplication of the (real/complex) numbers is commutative, unlike the multiplication of matrices.

Comment: I can just simply put a negative sign for this?

Comment: @dembrownies what do you mean? Your answer is the same as the given answer.

Comment: I thought I can only have the negative sign if I interchange the rows

Comment: There is no interchange of rows.  There are no negative signs to account for.  Your answer and the book answer are the same  $(y-x)(z-x)(z-y) = (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$

Comment: I guess I got confused with some other stuff. Thank you!

Comment: As @DougM affirmed it, it's the good answer.